# How to get complete bytes for unicode characters in C#?

Tags: c#, unicode, character

For the symbol greater than `>` I need to get the complete bytes, which I understand to be `\u003E`. Now C# only gives me `3E`. Is there anyway to get all the characters? i.e. `\u003E`.

I am using the following line of code.

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(">");
```

In a text file I have the following

```
\u003c
```

Which I need to search down at the byte level

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "complete bytes"? A character can be encoded in many different ways. I suspect you're confused about how text to binary encodings work - if you can give more information about the higher-level problem you're trying to solve, we'll be able to help more. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: All the characters? What does that even mean? All of the bytes? In what encoding?

Comment: `003C` is UTF-16 Big-Endian, not UTF-8.

Comment: I think you are asking the question backwards, right? You have a text file containing things like `\u003E` which you need to parse, is that the problem?

Comment: @Mr Lister. yes I am parsing the file but I have to do the parsing at the byte level. I cannot convert the file encoding. It has to be kept intact.

Answer (score 2):

The answer you get is correct - `3E` is the hex representation of `U+003E`.

If you want the unicode bytes (ie 2 byte array) then simply use this encoding:

```
Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(">");
```

Answer (score 2):

In UTF-8 the (ASCII range) char `>` is encoded into 1 byte.

If you want the string `"003E"` you can use:

```
  Encoding.Utf8.GetBytes(">")[0].ToString("X4");
```

and maybe add "\u" in front.

If you want an array of 2 bytes conataining { 0x00, 0x3E } then use

```
  Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(">");
```

Comment: UTF8 in capitals. `"\\u"+Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(">")[0].ToString("X4");`

Answer (score 2):

What bytes make up `>` differs from encoding to encoding - in UTF8 it really is only `0x3e`, in Unicode it is `0x00 0x3e`, so you need

```
Encoding.XXXX.GetBytes(">");
```

with XXXX being the encoding of your choice, e.g. `UTF8` or `Unicode`

Comment: In Unicode it is a code point whose number is 0x3e hex, there is no notion of how many bytes are used to represent it.  The UTF16 encoding uses two bytes, UTF8 uses one byte, UTF32 uses four bytes.

Comment: "Unicode" as in the sense of the word used in the .Net Framework allways refers to UTF16 - you are completly right, that this is not the dictionary definition, it is just the "Microsoft shorthand". Please understand my usage of "Unicode" in this context.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a rather lengthy piece at http://www.hackcraft.net/xmlUnicode/#sect4 some years back, that says the following in more detail, but:

`>` is a character. It's a purely conceptual item that we understand as having one or more meanings, uses and ways of writing it depending on different lingual and textual contexts. It's an abstract concept rather than anything we can actually make use of in a computer.

`U+003E` (which in C# is represented as `\u003E`) is a code-point. It's a way of assigning a number to a character, but it's still a rather abstract thing. The number `0x3E` (62) is still an abstract concept rather than something we can use in a computer.

`00111110`, `0000000000111110`, `0011111000000000`, `00000000000000000000000000111110` and `00111110000000000000000000000000` are all different ways commonly used to represent that code-point in actual 1s and 0s that computers can represent by pulses of electrical charge.

In between, as programmers we tend to think of those three as either `0x3E`, `0x003E` or `0x000000003E` which are numbers mapped to datatypes we actually use. The difference between `0000000000111110` and `0011111000000000` for this is one of endian-ness and mostly we don't think of it at this point having already (if necessary) thought "must make sure the endianness is correct", because that "if necessary" tends to happen at a level where one doesn't think of characters at all.

Actually, as programmers we tend to think of it mostly as the `>` we started with. Abstractions are great.

Your code that uses UTF-8 is using one of the different ways of turning characters into bytes, the one that turns U+003E into 0x3E. There are others, though UTF-8 is the one most useful for most interchange. It is therefore one of the correct answers to "the complete bytes for '>'". The byte 0x00 followed by 0x3E and the byte 0x3E followed by 0x00 would be two other correct answers, both forms of UTF-16 with different endianness. The byte sequences 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3E and 0x3E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 would both be correct UTF-32.

If you have a reason for wanting a particular one of these, use the appropriate encoding. If in doubt, use UTF-8 as you were doing.